# how to get ids of the rows updated by updateAll() function in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am developing an application in cakephp. I need to get id's of all the rows that have been updated using updateAll() function in cakephp. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanx..

Is this what i should do in my App Model

```
class AppModel extends Model {

    var $infos = array();

    function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {
        $this->$infos = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
        $return = parent::updateAll($fields, $conditions);
        $this->afterUpdateAll();
        return $return;
    }


    function afterUpdateAll(){
        foreach ($this->$infos as $info) {
            //do something
        }
    }

}
```

Will this work..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to issue a `find` passing the same conditions you passed to `updateAll`.

If the update operation changes data in any of the columns used in the conditions, you should use `find` *before* calling `updateAll`.

Comment: @vin.it, there is a catch on the code you posted, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanx.. will let you know.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you `UPDATE` uncial rows - you may  just `SELECT` them again after `UPDATE`